# Windows 10 won't boot after Ubuntu dual boot install. GRUB menu goes to black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, grub2, bios

I downloaded ubuntu on my computer that has windows 10 installed. However, after installing ubuntu I can not longer get back to windows. I can not get Grub to launch, holding shift does nothing and when I press escape my screen goes black and nothing happens no matter what I press. My computer is on but I am not able to do anything until I restart. Once I restart my computer, then ubuntu will launch again. I also can not access my bios and my bios splash screen does not appear. I have an NZXT b550 motherboard and can no longer get into my bios. I changed my Grub file to have the timeout set to ten and I changed the timeout display from hidden to menu. If anyone has any suggestions I would love any help please.

Comment: when you boot into Ubuntu, could you launch a terminal konsole " ctrl + alt + T " and copy paste this command;))   awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg   ((:in the terminal and paste that result into the comments or into your question. *just copy the part of code between the backward bracket and paste into terminal*

Comment: You could try this for getting into BIOS. -Your Motherboard for BIOS seems to be press F2 or Del continuously.

Comment: You may need "cold" boot or full power down & drain all power. Then you should be able to press f2 or whatever is correct key for your system to get into UEFI/IBIOS. Are both systems installed in same boot mode. With that system they both should be UEFI, not very old BIOS.

Comment: beaux@Bo-Ubuntu:~$ awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-89-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-89-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-67-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-67-generic (recovery mode)
Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)
UEFI Firmware Settings

Comment: Here is the output of the command @Nishnabe

Comment: Windows and Linux is in the GRUB. If you edited your GRUB like you said, you should be able to see a GRUB menu pop up at boot and give you the option to select Windows or Linux OS. Do you see that when you boot? Was it set up correctly? Getting to that GRUB menu at boot is where you want to be to select the correct operating system.

Comment: Note: you don't have to hit any key to get the GRUB menu, if you set it correct it will auto pop up for 10 seconds during boot up.

Comment: Did you disable secure boot and disable windows fast start up before installing? You will have to provide more info. Maybe edit your questions title and add more info to body. Title like this maybe... Win10 won't boot after Ubuntu dual boot install. Then use tags, GRUB, Boot, Dual Boot, BIOS, ...etc

Answer (score 0):

It is most possible that Windows and Ubuntu are not installed in the same boot mode, that is one is in UEFI, and another is in BIOS mode. One trick could help you to get the GRUB menu and with that the access to both systems: install Ubuntu again in legacy ( BIOS ) mode, I think that the menu item is something like "Try and install Ubuntu in graphics safe mode". That will bring you into very low display resoulution mode, but if you accept the defaults you will get through the installation, and after that you will have GRUB.